# The Haar basis, proof of orthonormality.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Please i have this problem and i known how to prove completeness but do not know how to prove that it is orthonormal. I will appreciate it if anyone can help me.
 Given that $n\geq1$ write $n=k+2^p$,where $p\geq0$ and $k\geq0$  are integers uniquely determined by the condition $k\leq2^p-1$. consider the function defined on $(0,1)$ by$$\psi_{n}(t)=\begin{cases} 2^{p/2}, &  2^{-p}k < t < 2^{-p}(k+1/2)\\-2^{p/2} ,&  2^{-p}(k+1/2) < t < 2^{-p}(k+1) \\ 0, & \textrm{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$ Set $\psi_0\equiv$ 1 and prove that $(\psi_n)_{n\geq0}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2(0,1)$.

Comment: This is as easy as $1\cdot 1!+1\cdot(-1)=0$ and $1^2+(-1)^2=2$. Where exactly are your difficulties? Did you check the support of these functions? The preimages of their function values?

Comment: Just tell me the steps needed and i will  do that because i dont really know how to go about it.Thanks

Comment: These are the steps needed. For different wavelets on the same scale they have disjoint support, up to single points, and for wavelets on different scales, one of them is constant on the support of the other.

Comment: i was just able to show that it is complete can you help me with showing that it is orthogonal and orthonormal? Thanks